# Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function in Jamsine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Unit testing in Angular using Jasmine and Karma. I've written a spec file but I'm getting an error. Let me first show what I've done so far. I've created a custom component:

**TimeselectorComponent**

```
startRange = moment('12-01-01');
endRange = moment ('12-12-01');

modes= ['Calendar Year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling Year', 'Custom'];

date = new Date();
currentYear = this.date.getFullYear(); // or simply currentYear = 2020;

@ViewChild('primaryMonthPicker') primaryMonthPicker: MonthpickerComponent; // a child component

primaryDropDown(startRange, endRange) {
    if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[0]) {
        this.initCalendarYear(this.primaryMonthPicker, this.currentYear);
    } else if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[1]) {
        this.initYearToDate(this.primaryMonthPicker, this.currentYear);
    } else if (this.primaryMode === this.modes[2]) {
        this.initRollingYear(this.primaryMonthPicker, this.currentYear);
    }
}
```

In the above code `MonthpickerComponent` is another custom component which is the only child component of `TimeselectorComponent`.

I just want to check when `primaryDropDown` is called then `initCalendarYear` should also be called. Here's the spec file:

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TimeselectorComponent } from './timeselector.component';
...

describe('TimeselectorComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TimeselectorComponent>;

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-monthpicker',
        template: '<div></div>'
    })
    class FakeMonthpickerComponent {
        // methods of MonthpickerComponent
    }

    let MODES = [];

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        MODES = ['Calendar Year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling Year', 'Custom'];
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [FakeMonthpickerComponent, TimeselectorComponent],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimeselectorComponent);
    });

    // other test cases that are passing

    // need help with this test case
    it('should call initCalendarYear when primaryDropDown is called', () => {
      const startRange=moment('2020-01-01');
      const endRange= moment('2020-12-01');
      spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'initCalendarYear');
      fixture.componentInstance.primaryMode=MODES[0];
      fixture.componentInstance.primaryDropDown(startRange, endRange);
     expect(fixture.componentInstance.initCalendarYear).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But I'm getting this error:
[image]

I have to test whether correct method is called for associated `if-else` statement. Please help me.

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbpmju).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TimeselectorComponent } from './timeselector.component';
import { Component, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
var moment = require('moment/moment')

describe('TimeselectorComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TimeselectorComponent>;

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-monthpicker',
        template: '<div></div>'
    })
    class FakeMonthpickerComponent {
        // methods of MonthpickerComponent
    }

    let MODES = [];

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        MODES = ['Calendar Year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling Year', 'Custom'];
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [FakeMonthpickerComponent, TimeselectorComponent],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimeselectorComponent);
    });

    // other test cases that are passing

    // need help with this test case
    it('should call initCalendarYear when primaryDropDown is called', () => {
      const startRange=moment('2020-01-01');
      const endRange= moment('2020-12-01');
      spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'initCalendarYear');
      fixture.componentInstance.primaryMode=MODES[0];
      fixture.componentInstance.primaryDropDown(startRange, endRange);
     expect(fixture.componentInstance.initCalendarYear).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The above game me success :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: But there's no return value that I want to mock. I tried passing simply `true`. That didn't work. And also in `expect(...` statement what should I pass `(????, 2020)`.

Comment: Can you please give a more concrete answer. That will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually a mock object is generally created, when you are testing a component and you don't want to use real implementation of service and you just want when you component calls a service method, real implementation should be replaced by mock one and just should return a value without performing any logic. spyon helps to create a mock. and methods like toHaveBeenCalled can only me checked on a mock/spy object.

Comment: Hi. I'm still having some other problems. Since we're on the same time zone. Can we have a skype call please.

Comment: @AakashGarg. I've some new requirements. I've edited the question. Can you please check once more.

Comment: this is not the correct way, one you got solution of a question you should mark the found answer as answer and post new questions as questions. also in your case when you raise a new question a stackblitz would be needed.

Comment: @AakashGarg, Yes you are right. And I'm very sorry for that. I'll be careful next time for sure.

Comment: @AakashGarg, i tried creating stackblitz but it was not possible because it is company's code (but nothing copyrighted) but we're using some libraries of our own.

Comment: create a minimal example yourself. don't copy exact code.

Comment: @AakashGarg, Here's the stackblitz for which I want to write the test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbpmju

Comment: Strange. I'm getting this error: Expected spy initCalendarYear to have been called. With exactly same copy-paste code.

Comment: i ran it on stackblitz you gave.

Comment: If I remove `fixture.componentInstance.primaryMode=MODES[0];` from the case then it is working fine

Comment: not sure, what you are doing wrong, but you can mark this as a answer because your main question was spy object

Comment: Please share your stackblitz. I want to take reference from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a spy like this

```
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'initCalendarYear');
```

Change the last line by this

```
expect(fixture.componentInstance.initCalendarYear).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

So your final test case should look like this

```
it('should call initCalendarYear when primaryDropDown is called', () => {
        const startRange=moment('2020-01-01');
        const endRange= moment('2020-12-01');
        fixture.componentInstance.primaryMode = MODES[0];
        spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'initCalendarYear');
        fixture.componentInstance.primaryDropDown(startRange, endRange);

  expect(fixture.componentInstance.initCalendarYear).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
 });
```

Comment: This is perfect. But I've a small change in the requirement. I wanted to show you. Is it possible on skype now ?

Comment: Not possible to join on skype, if you can explain it here that would be great.

Comment: Yes. Give me a moment I'm trying to create a stackblitz or something similar.

Comment: Creating stackblitz was taking longer than expected. So I edited the question itself. I'll want to write different test cases for each `if-else` block separately.

Comment: But no. See I'm calling 3 different methods, `initCalendarYear`, `initYearToDate` and `initRollingYear`. Though parameters are same for all 3 but the business logic is different.

Comment: Suggest you to have three seperate test cases for each conditions by passing values to `this.primaryMode`, il update the ans for one test, you can refer that and then add test cases for  two other cases.

Comment: Yes, that's all I want. I'll create 3 different `it(...)` one for each case. But on doing `fixture.componentInstance.primaryMode=MODES[0];` my test case is failing for first case itself.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And i dont see the declaration of `primaryMode` variable in the component code as well

Comment: Ok. Then I think a minimal stackblitz is mandatory here. Give me 5 mins please. I'll quickly come back

Comment: Here is the minimal stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbpmju